Questions about trading mechanics, brokers, trading technology, etc
I've been monitoring this site for a while, reading and learning. Recently I decided to try out few own ideas. 
The thing is I have couple of questions which may seem basic to the most people here, however I am not sure that the answers I was able to obtain are reliable/true. Most of my questions are related to the trading mechanics, how brokers work, how APIs work, etc..
So I was wondering whether questions like these are in scope of this site.
Thanks!

Can you ask these kinds of questions to your professors or coworkers?

I'm not sure I follow your question.. How my coworkers relate to that :)

If it's an "easy" question related to how the stock market works, then just talk to your colleagues. You do work in the industry, right? We are very clear about the kinds of questions we allow on here.

No, actually I'm not a pro and do not work in this industry. So I guess this is not the place for this kind of questions. I wonder if there another QnA site on stackexchange which will be more appropriate for this type of questions. Thank you.

Questions about basic finance and definitions may be addressed to http://money.stackexchange.com/
